# Finding nodes that have no text with XPath and Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

I have XML files like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<file_name fileNamee="test1">
  <xmlID idName="1">
    <expr mode="inline" xml:id="1">
      <App>
        <Tok font="medium" meaning="less-than-or-equals" name="lea" role="RELOP">≤</Tok>
        <Tok font="medium italic" role="UNKNOWN">d</Tok>
        <App>
          <Tok font="medium" meaning="minus" role="ADDOP">-</Tok>
          <App>
            <Tok meaning="times" role="MULOP"> </Tok>
            <Tok font="medium italic" name="phi" possibleFunction="yes" role="UNKNOWN">ϕ</Tok>
            <Tok close=")" font="medium italic" open="(" role="UNKNOWN">k</Tok>
          </App>
          <Tok font="medium" meaning="2" role="NUMBER">2</Tok>
        </App>
      </App>
    </expr>
  </xmlID>
```

Using XPath, I want to find all Tok nodes that have text and also those which have no text.

I tried:

```
tree = etree.parse(xmlFile) 
textTok = tree.xpath('//Tok[text()]')
```

it works and return all Tok nodes that have text.

But how can I get all Tok nodes that have no text using xpath expression?

thanks

Comment: Not really familiar with Python; are you sure that this `iter()` method takes an XPath expression as an argument? You should add a complete, verifiable Python script to your question anyway.

Comment: yes thanks for your reply it solve part of the problem so I edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how can I get all Tok nodes that have no text using xpath expression?

You get `Tok` elements that do not contain text with

```
noTextTok = tree.xpath('//Tok[not(text())]')
```

Note that the input sample you show is *not* well-formed XML. The value of `xml:id` cannot start with a number:

```
<expr mode="inline" xml:id="1">
```

Also, there are not `Tok` element nodes without text in the sample.